# Is there a limit to grouping rows in poi excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So as I am using apache poi and the groupRow method to group data when creating an excel sheet, I am always hitting a limit of 99 rows when grouping.

My peers don't seem to know anything about this and I have also searched online and found nothing about this method having a limit. When you just open any excel file you can group more than 100 rows, however when I am creating a sheet by java, grouping only works up to 99 rows.

I might be missing something so I will put up the portion of code.

- I get the count of rows grouped by division using sql as 'mapList'. Then I add them while creating rows with repeat.
- The main data list(resultList) starts at row 12 in the created excel sheet(so 11 in this code)

Thank you in advance!

```
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++){
           row = sheet.createRow(i + 11);
           cell = row.createCell(0);

           //*..... go on to make cells then I start grouping*

           int currentRow = i+11;
           int startRow = 0;
           int endRow = 0;

           for(int j = 0; j < mapList.size(); j++) {

             int checkRow = 11+Integer.parseInt(mapList.get(j).get("count").toString());
            
             if(currentRow == checkRow) {
                 endRow = 11+Integer.parseInt(mapList.get(j).get("count").toString())-2;
                
                 startRow = endRow - //*previous group's row +2 here*;      
                
                 sheet.groupRow(startRow, endRow); // the grouping method
                 break;
              } 
            }
         }
```

Comment: There is no such limit. I am able creating `Excel` sheets having grouped rows having much bigger row count per group. What exactly is your issue? Do you get exceptions? Which? Or is the result not useable in `Excel`? What message you get from `Excel` while opening the workbook?

Comment: No exceptions, only not getting the result I am aiming for. As in the question above, I am trying to group rows of data and set them to collapse on opening the excel file. If I use the group function without any for statements, grouping works without any limits. However, when I use a for statement for grouping, it only groups rows up to 99.